# Angular :ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables,

Tags: angular

Please I have this error, I tried several methods but it doesn't work. I am working with service to get a list of assignments from my MongoDB database but I have this error "Angular:ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables,", the problem is on getAssignment()

## My Service

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Assignment} from '../assignments/assignment.model';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {LoggingService} from './logging.service';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AssignmentsService {


  assignments: Assignment[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nom: 'Assignment 1',
      dateRendu: new Date('2020-12-01'),
      rendu: true,
      auteur: 'Asmaa',
      note: 12,
      remarques: 'tres bien'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      auteur: 'Asmaa',
      note: 14,
      remarques: 'bien',
      nom: 'Assignment 2',
      dateRendu: new Date('2020-12-02'),
      rendu: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nom: 'Assignment 3',
      dateRendu: new Date('2020-12-03'),
      rendu: false,
      auteur: 'Manel',
      note: 14,
      remarques: 'bien',

    },
  ];

  constructor(private loggingService: LoggingService,
              private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  uri = 'http://localhost:8010/api/assignments'

  getAssignments() {

    return this.http.get<Assignment>(this.uri)

  }


  getAssignment(id: number): Observable<Assignment | undefined> {
    /*const a:Assignment|undefined =
           this.assignments.find(a => a.id === id);
    return of(a);*/
    return this.http.get<Assignment>(this.uri + "/" + id)
  }

  addAssignment(assignment: Assignment): Observable<any> {
    // this.loggingService.log(assignment,"ajouté");
    // this.assignments.push(assignment);
    console.log('done');

    return this.http.post(this.uri, assignment);

  }

  deleteAssignment(assignment: Assignment): Observable<string> {
    this.loggingService.log(assignment, "supprimé");

    this.assignments.forEach((a, index) => {
        if (a === assignment) {
          this.assignments.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    );
    return of('assignement supprimé');

  }

  updateAssignment(assignment: Assignment): Observable<string> {
    this.assignments.forEach((a, index) => {
      if (assignment === a) {
        this.assignments[index] = a;
      }

    });
    return of('assignement modifié');
  }
}
```

## My Html

```html
<!--<main *ngIf="!formActive">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAddAssignmentBtnClick()">Ajouter un devoir</button>

-->

<a routerLink="/add">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Ajouter un devoir</button>
</a>

<mat-list *ngFor="let assignment of assignments ">
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/assignment/{{this.assignment.id}}">
      <mat-list-item (click)="assignmentCliquer(assignment)">
        <p *ngIf="assignment.rendu; else nonsoumis">
          Devoir intitulé {{ assignment.nom }}, rendu le
          {{ assignment.dateRendu }}.
        </p>
        <ng-template #nonsoumis>
          Le devoir {{ assignment.nom }} n'a pas été rendu.
        </ng-template>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </mat-list-item>
    </a>
  </nav>
</mat-list>
<!--
<app-assignment-detail [assignmentTransmis]="assignmentSelectionne" ></app-assignment-detail>

-->
```

## My Component

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AssignmentsService} from '../shared/assignments.service';
import {Assignment} from './assignment.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-assignments',
  templateUrl: './assignments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assignments.component.css'],
})
export class AssignmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  titre = 'Liste des Assignments';
  ajoutActive = false;
  formActive = false;
  nomDevoir: string = '';
  dateDevoir: Date = new Date();
  assignmentSelectionne!: Assignment;
  assignments!: Assignment[];

  constructor(private assignmentsService: AssignmentsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAssignments();

  }

  getAssignments() {

    this.assignmentsService.getAssignments().subscribe(
      (assignments: any) => {
        this.assignments = assignments;

      }
    );
  }

  assignmentCliquer(assignment: Assignment) {
    this.assignmentSelectionne = assignment;
  }

  //onAddAssignmentBtnClick(){
  //this.formActive = true;

  //}
  //onNouvelAssignement(event: any){
  // this.formActive = false;
  //this.assignments.push(event);
  //this.assignmentsService.addAssignment(event).subscribe(message=>console.log(message));

  // }
}
```

I hope to find the solution

Comment: Have you ensured the response is array indeed?(it usually occurs when you’re manipulating through an object and not an array), It will be much easier if you can attach the response from the server

Comment: I don't how can I ensure this?

Comment: F12 > Network tab > assignments call > Preview

Comment: Or in another way, is to past the url (which in your case is - http://localhost:8010/api/assignments) in a new browser tab, and this will be your response

Comment: it displays on the network preview failed to load response data

Comment: Can you add that full code to stackblitz ? I'm sure I can fix that error.

Comment: The NG02200 says, that the iterator should run on array and not an object, which I'm almost certain that the response that returns from the server is an object :)

Comment: Try printing the `assignments` in the getAssignments() function in  your component class and share with us what is printed then  we can help you out, as @AviSiboni said, it is most probably the object that is why the ngFor is not able to iterate over the elements

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the errooor**

```
assignments.component.ts:28 ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe? Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG02200
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3218:31)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2720:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2679:17)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.mjs:2611:5)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11136:21)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:12188:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10918:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11177:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12142:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11151:9)
load (async)        
getAssignments  @   assignments.component.ts:28
ngOnInit    @   assignments.component.ts:22
Show 105 more frames
```

Comment: You can edit your question to include this error

Comment: you should edit your question. move your answer's content to question